# Message Delivery Guarantee for Multiple Consumers in Pub/Sub and Messaging Queues

Tags: redis, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe, messaging

**Requirement**

A system undergoes some state change, and multiple other parts of the system has to know this(lets call them observers) so that they can perform some actions based on the current state, the actions of the observers are important, if some of the observers are not online(not listening currently due to some trouble, but will be back soon), the message should not be discarded till all the observers gets the message.

Trying to accomplish this with pub/sub model, here are my findings, (please correct if this understanding is wrong) -

The publisher creates an event on specific topic, and multiple subscribers can consume the *same* message. This model either provides no delivery guarantee(in redis), or delivery is guaranteed once(with messaging queues), ie. when one of the consumer acknowledges a message, the message is discarded(rabbitmq).

**Example**

A new Person Profile entity gets created in DB

Now,

1. A background verification service has to know this to trigger the verification process.
2. Subscriptions service has to know this to add default subscriptions to the user.

Now both the tasks are important, unrelated and can run in parallel.

Now In Queue model, if subscription service is down for some reason, a BG verification process acknowledges the message, the message will be removed from the queue, or if it is fire and forget like most of pub/sub, the delivery is anyhow not guaranteed for both the services.

One more point is both the tasks are unrelated and need not be triggered one after other.

---

In short, my need is to make sure all the consumers gets the *same* message and they should be able to *acknowledge them individually*, the message should be *evicted only after all the consumers acknowledged it* either of the above approaches doesn't do this.

Anything I am missing here ? How should I approach this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This scenario is explicitly supported by [RabbitMQ's model](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html), which separates "exchanges" from "queues":

- A publisher always sends a message to an "exchange", which is just a stateless routing address; it doesn't need to know what queue(s) the message should end up in
- A consumer always reads messages from a "queue", which contains its own copy of messages, regardless of where they originated
- Multiple consumers can subscribe to the *same* queue, and each message will be delivered to *exactly one* consumer
- Crucially, an exchange can route the same message to *multiple* queues, and each will receive a *copy* of the message

The key thing to understand here is that while we talk about consumers "subscribing" to a queue, the "subscription" part of a "pub-sub" setup is actually the routing from the exchange to the queue.

So a RabbitMQ pub-sub system might look like this:

1. A new Person Profile entity gets created in DB
2. This event is published as a message to an "events" [topic exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-python.html) with a routing key of "entity.profile.created"
3. The exchange routes copies of the message to multiple queues:

   - A "verification_service" queue has been bound to this exchange to receive a copy of all messages matching "entity.profile.#"
   - A "subscription_setup_service" queue has been bound to this exchange to receive a copy of all messages matching "entity.profile.created"
4. The consuming scripts don't know anything about this routing, they just know that messages will appear in the queue for events that are relevant to them:

   - The verification service picks up the copy of the message on the "verification_service" queue, processes, and acknowledges it
   - The subscription setup service picks up the copy of the message on the "subscription_setup_service" queue, processes, and acknowledges it
5. If there are multiple consuming scripts looking at the *same* queue, they'll share the messages *on that queue* between them, but still completely independent of any other queue.

Here's a screenshot from [this interactive visualisation tool](http://tryrabbitmq.com/) that shows this scenario:

[image: RabbitMQ visualisation showing a producer, an exchange, two queues, and three consumers]

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer clearly addresses all the points in my question. Two doubts -  1) Is the consumer binding to their individual queue happens by default ? If thats the case how would the exchange know to bind - 1queue:multiple consumers(like a job queue, whoever is free, get the task, acknowledge & remove the job from queue) vs 1queue:one consumer. Any explicit configurations ? 2) Is this model unique to rabbitmq or other majority of queue providers achieve this in some or other way ?

Comment: @YuvarajG There are two bindings: several queues can be bound to an exchange, and each get a _copy_ of the message, giving the "pub-sub" functionality; several _consumers_ can then bind to _one of those queues_, and will get the messages shared out between them, giving a "worker pool" functionality. Those two sets of bindings are completely independent - an exchange knows nothing about consumers, and a consumer knows nothing about exchanges. To be honest, I don't know much about other message queues and how their routing works, so can't answer that part.

Comment: The RabbitMQ site has lots of documentation and tutorials, which are well worth a read. You might also find playing with this tool helpful to visualise the process: http://tryrabbitmq.com/

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned it is not something that you can control with Redis Pub/Sub data structure.

But you can do it easily with [Redis Streams](https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro).

Streams will allow you to post messages using the `XADD` command and then control which consumers are dealing with the message and acknowledge that message has been processed.

You can look at these sample application that provides (in Java) example about:

- posting and consuming messages
- create multiple consumer groups
- manage exceptions

Links:

- [Getting Started with Redis Streams and Java](https://redislabs.com/blog/getting-started-with-redis-streams-and-java/)
- [Redis Streams in Action](https://github.com/tgrall/redis-streams-in-action) *( Project that shows how to use ADD/ACK/PENDING/CLAIM and build an error proof streaming application with Redis Streams and SpringData )*

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried redis streams before, I suppose the consumer groups in Redis are for consuming different portion of the message in one topic by different consumer groups, so the group1 is not consuming and acknowledging part of the message which is same as group2, right ? But I need consumers to get their own copy of full message and acknowledge the same. And i don't want to duplicate the messages by creating new queues each consumer.